# Permission Denied (Transmission WebUI)

Tags: server, permissions, transmission

So I have been playing with groups, users and permissions on my Home Server in order to use Transmission, to no avail.

I want to have my 'download' folder in my 'home' folder. Why? Because I have my external drive mounted to /home in order to have a larger library and my root folder is on the internal memory.

This is my `ls -l` output

```
total 16
drwsrwsrwx 2 debian-transmission drigy 4096 Mar 31 17:01 Movies
drwsrwsrwx 2 debian-transmission drigy 4096 Mar 31 17:01 Shows
drwsrwsrwx 2 debian-transmission drigy 4096 Mar 31 17:01 Sports
drwsrwsrwx 5 debian-transmission drigy 4096 Mar 31 17:38 data
```

Out of desperation, I have also set permissions to 777 recursively to all sub-directories.

At this point, I am out of ideas.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If there is a permissions issue, your `/var/log/syslog` file will contain very specific details about the error. This will make it much easier to determine what needs to be done and in what order 

Comment: By internal memory do you mean hard drive? A hard drive is not memory.

Comment: I kid you not, I woke up today, deleted syslog (may not have been of any consequence, just saying), checked transmission and it was working. No idea what happened. I appreciate you guys responding to my problem!

Comment: I have also changed debian-transmission in config to root.